# Check ntp server authentication with chronyd client

Tags: linux, ntp, chrony

Is there an alternative for `ntpq -c as`, while using chronyd as client?

While using ntpd as client, `ntpq -c as` provides details about authentication of  client to server using keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer after little experimenting.
`chronyc ntpdata`  will provide if the client authenticated to server.
Not as verbose as `ntpq -c  as`, but works.

One could use this command:

```sh
chronyc ntpdata | awk '/^Remote address/ || /^Authenticated/ { print; if (/^A/) print "" }'
```

The output might look like this:

```text
Remote address  : 94.130.49.186 (5E8231BA)
Authenticated   : No

Remote address  : 162.159.200.123 (A29FC87B)
Authenticated   : No

Remote address  : 131.234.220.231 (83EADCE7)
Authenticated   : No
```

Answer (score 0):

The command line interface to the `chronyd` daemon is [chronyc](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/doc/3.4/chronyc.html).

To see information about the system's clock performance:

```
chronyc tracking
```

To see the time sources being used:

```
chrony sourcestats
```

Comment: I know. But in chronyc, I cannot seem to find the same functionality as "ntpq -c as", which tells me if my client is able to authenticate to the server using keys.